# Using Firebase (NoSQL) for Inventory app is ACID or not?

Tags: firebase, data-structures, database-design, database, nosql

I'm a newbie programmer.

I want to get experience using Firebase (Backend As A Service) which use JSON for storing data (I think they call this type of database a document database).

But my Inventory app has 3 main page which are add item, inventory and item sold.

Can this be done using This type of database? is it still ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability)?

add item page would have {product name, date added, amount added}

Inventory page would have {product name, total amount, last date added}

When I click add item in the add item page how can I sync data between add item page and inventory page? (how to increment the total amount in the inventory page?) and will it be ACID? foe example when I click add item. the item is recorded in the add item page and while the incrementing is almost happening the electricity is fail and the result is there is a item in add item page but the increment is not happened because the electricity is off. which means this transaction is no longer atomic.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Firebase has a `transaction` method and validation rules, which could be combined to do many types of validations. To give you some idea of what's possible, read this article that explains secure item trading for games: http://edinburghhacklab.com/2014/01/firesafe-a-prophylactic-for-firebase/. So: yes, it can be built.

Comment: Dear Frank van Puffelen, Thank you for your reply. I have looked at the Firebase doc and seems like the transaction is using to ensure that the saving is not mass up with other saving. What I'm looking for is kind of One to many and Many to Many relationship. Because working with Firebase sometime need denormalize especially in my case. How can I ensure that the data in two source is updated and if there is failure both will not get updated (Atomically) can you please suggest me on this topic?

Comment: The article I linked to describes exactly that: a game where two players trade items.

Comment: I mean only one user update into two data source. not between user. or your link can be applied to make one user?

Comment: The fact that only a single user is involved in your case, just makes it a bit simpler than the one in the article. The article describes (IIRC) a variant of a two-phase commit, which can be an interesting area for you to further research.

Comment: They say this at the end of the article. "We do not make any promises about the correctness of this protocol" So should i use the method?